# jquery ui tooltip with html form inside, or html content

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tooltip

I am looking for examples for the new jquery ui tooltip that has HTML forms inside.

Jquery ui only has simple demos so far, but it may be already possible:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tooltip

I am looking for replicating the jquery tools tooltip
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html
, which can easily contain html forms, and the tooltip persists while mouse is over it. In jquery ui, currently it seems tooltip fades out when mouse moves away from the element triggering it.

Comment: yeah because this would be not tooltip.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip
you want to create a small dialogbox.

Comment: Would you have any examples for this with jquery ui? I only found plugins, but not with raw core :) It seems it would be extremely hackish to get all the positioning, window collision detection etc.